# how to apply if and else if conditon in mysql Stored procedure

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `apply_Leave_SP`(
in leavetypeid int ,
in empid int,
in reason varchar(100),
in startdate date,
in enddate date,
in startsession int,
in endsession int,
in compoffid int,
in mangerid int

)
BEGIN

declare leavestatus int(10) default 0;
declare optionalyHolidays int(10) default 0;
declare listofholidays int(10) default 0;
declare totalhours int (10) default 0;
declare hours int (10) default 0;
declare satsun int (10) default 0;
declare manger_id int(10) default 0;
declare paidleave int(10) default 0;   
declare days int(10) default 0;
declare leaveappliedid int(10) default 0;
declare lossofpay int(10) default 0;
declare casualleave int (10) default 0;
declare sickleave int (10) default 0;


  select count(holiday_id) into optionalyHolidays from Parabola.holidays where holiday_type_id=2 and 
                          DATEDIFF(startdate,curdate())>=20;

    select count(*) into listofholidays from Parabola.holidays where date between startdate and enddate;                      

 SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS total into hours
FROM 
(   SELECT ADDDATE(startdate, INTERVAL @i:=@i+1 DAY) AS DAY
    FROM (
        SELECT a.a
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS a
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS b
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS a UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS c
    ) a
    JOIN (SELECT @i := -1) r1
    WHERE 
    @i < DATEDIFF(enddate, startdate)

) AS dateTable
WHERE WEEKDAY(dateTable.Day) IN (5,6);

       SELECT  datediff(enddate,startdate) into totalhours; 
       set hours=(totalhours-listofholidays-satsun)*8;


    if(leavetypeid=1)then
     set leavestatus=5;
     else
      set leavestatus=1;
       end if;    

       if(optionalyHolidays>=0) then
       set leavestatus=5;
       end if;

insert into leave_applied(leave_type_id,hours,employee_id,
created_at,updated_at,start_date,end_date,start_date_session,
end_date_session,reason,
status,reminder_count,personal_calendar_event_id,system_calendar_event_id)

values(leavetypeid,hours,empid,curdate(),curdate(),startdate,enddate,
startsession,endsession,
reason,leavestatus,1,'sdasdas','sadeew');



Select LAST_INSERT_ID() into leaveappliedid ;


        if((leaveappliedid=1 or 4) and days >paidleave) then
            set lossofpay=days-paidleave;


        else if((leaveappliedid=1 or 4) and days> @CL) then
           set sickleave=days-@CL;
           set casualleave=@CL;


        else     if((leaveappliedid=1 or 4)  and days>@SL) then 
            set casualleave=days-@SL;
            set sickleave=@SL;

            else
            set mangerid=10;

            end if; 

        end;

    insert into leave_actual (leave_applied_id,
     leave_type_id,hours,start_date,
     end_date,created_at,updated_at) values(leaveappliedid,leavetypeid,
     hours,start_date,end_date,curdate(),curdate());     


insert into leave_approval (leave_applied_id,
         manager_id,status ,created_at,updated_at) values
         (leaveappliedid,mangerid,leavestatus,curdate(),curdate());   

  END
```

this my code when i try to apply else if condition then there is Syntax Error is coming  while  only with if there is no Error is coming but i have to apply else if condition  please suggest me where am doing wrong it show else if Condition

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The syntax of if, else if is like this:

```
IF condition THEN
    ... ...
ELSEIF condition THEN
    ... ...
END IF;
```

See [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) here.

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
    [ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

Comment: i have tried same but at then last Line END there is error coming it show SYntax error missing IF

Comment: @ResearchDevelopment Sorry, I've missed `IF`, updated it, check again please.

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/PaM93CQhPXTvxKFcvPzHpx  i have done same thing then also Error is coming missing if

Comment: `ELSE IF` is different from `ELSEIF`, there is no space between `ELSE` and `IF`. @ResearchDevelopment